# Date Picker Issue with IE 11 (using JavaScript, JSF ) after refresh it works but before refresh it doen't

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am using Javascript in an xhtml file of `jsf` for `datepicker`. It works fine in Firefox, but not on IE 11.

```
<h:panelGrid id="expirationPanel">
<h:selectOneRadio id="  "layout=" " style="height:75px;" value="#{ManagedBean.xxxx}">                                                               
<f:selectItem itemValue="no" itemLabel=""/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="yes" itemLabel=""/>
<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{ManagedBean.yyyy}" immediate="true" oncomplete="reRenderexPanel()"/>                         
</h:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGrid id="expdPanel" columns="1" style="height:70px;">
<div style="margin-top:8px;">
<h:panelGrid id="zzzz" columns="1" style="height:22px;">
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.cet_never}" style="color:black;font-size:12px;" />
</h:panelGrid>  
</div>
<h:panelGrid id="ex" columns="2" style="height:40px;">
<r:calendar value="#{ManagedBean.ed}" id="ed" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" showApplyButton="false" locale="en_US" enableManualInput="true" converter="dateConverter"    
disabled="#{ManagedBean.ieDisabled()}">                             
<f:validator validatorId="checkvaliddate" />    
<f:attribute name="butClick" value="createUserForm:expirationDate:butClick" />                                                              
</r:calendar>   
<h:message for="exDate" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

There are two radio buttons when I am changing the radio button then it does not work after refresh it works in IE11.

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:x="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:r="http://richfaces.org/rich"
 xmlns:j4fry="http://j4fry.org/jsf">

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible reasons for your not refreshing problem :

- The immediate attribute set to true cause the JSL lifecycle to skip the validation and the update model phase.
- Can't you let the jsf framework itself to update your expirationPanel component using reRender instead of doing it by the js oncomplete ?

`<a4j:support event="onclick" action="#{ManagedBean.yyyy}" reRender="expirationPanel"/>`

Comment: Is the action ManagedBean.yyyy really executed when the radio btn is clicked ? Is there an error message in the javascript console of your IE browser (F12) when the radio btn is clicked ?

Comment: Yes It is excuted when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: The problem is it is working fine with other browser like Firefox, Chrome,IE5,IE6,...

But it is not working with IE11

Comment: There are two radio button when I select the radio button for date picker and referesh the page then calendar comes but when I select other and then I select date picker radio button and click on the date picker image then that doesn't come.